# Regex to extract first two numbers of a date

Tags: mysql, regex

I have date written like this : 01/12/2013 -- how can I display only the first two letter using REGEXP. Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use a regex? Seems like overkill to me.

Comment: my query goes like this 'SELECT date FROM entrydate WHERE date REGEXP '^[[:DIGIT:]]'' i want only to match the first two letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function instead of a regexp:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '/', 1)
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: you should use an alias `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '/', 1) AS newcolumnname FROM yourtable` and get `$row['newcolumnname']`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `LEFT` function

```
SELECT LEFT(datecol,2) FROM `table`
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/27933)

Comment: I got Undefined index:

Comment: @user3103905 show your query

Comment: `<?php

 $sql = "SELECT LEFT(date, 2) FROM entry";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "" .$row['date']. "</br>";
 }
     ?>`

Comment: @user3103905 this error is comming from php not from mysql try this `SELECT LEFT(date, 2) date_col FROM entry` and in php in loop `echo $row['date_col'];`

Comment: @user3103905 if the solutions provided for your problems worked you need to choose the best one and mark it as solved for more help visit [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)